# Node cannot recognise any module

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have started working with NodeJS recently and everything was fine until recently my Node has stopped recognising any module.

I have been stuck for more than 4 hours now and have tried uninstalling node and reinstalling it but it is not working.

Also I am seeing that while I use `npm install` it is installing `express` in the global directory not locally.

I am unable to find any reason to it and it would be great if anyone can help with this.

This is not a repeat question please the issue seems unresolved at this point

Exact error is:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'bcrypt'
Require stack:
- /home/devesh/projects/app/logger.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/devesh/projects/app/logger.js:1:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/devesh/projects/app/logger.js' ]
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "logger.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: what do you mean `node has stopped recognising any module`? what is the error?

Comment: Please post your `package.json` (edit your question and put it in there). Then make sure you have navigated inside your project folder before running `npm` commands.

Comment: Try running `npm init -y` before installing the modules

Comment: I have shared the exact error and package.json

Comment: my bad, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved and I was installing in global so had to use
`npm link <package-name> --local` to resolve the issue.

Comment: While this might solve your problem, `npm link` has another purpose and you probably don't want to use it. A `npm install <package-name>` called in the directory should install it in the `node_modules` directory there. Only a `npm install -g <package-name>` should install it globally. So there has to be something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **dependencies** and also require **"bcrypt"**

Install in terminal : **npm i bcryptjs**

Package.json : (After Installing)

```
"dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
         }
```

app.js: (Require bcrypt)

```
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
```